# R & Shiny – Updating dynamic number of reactive plots once dynamically generated

Tags: r

I am putting together a simple reporting system, but I'm falling at the first hurdle trying to put this together in Shiny instead of my usual goto route of Python/PHP.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(googleAnalyticsR)

server <- function(input, output) {

  id <- 'XXXXXXX'

  #dynamically create the right number of output
  output$plots <- renderUI({

    web_data <- google_analytics_4(id, 
                                   date_range = c(format(input$dates[1]), format(input$dates[2])),
                                   metrics = c("sessions","pageviews","bounces"),
                                   dimensions = c("date", "channelGrouping"),
                                   anti_sample = TRUE)

    plot_output_list <- lapply(unique(web_data$channelGrouping), function(i) {
      plotname <- paste0("plot", i)
      plotOutput(plotname)
    })

    tagList(plot_output_list)



  }) 

  for (channel in unique(web_data$channelGrouping)) {
    local({ 
      plotname <- paste0("plot", channel)
      localChannel <- channel
      filtered_data <- subset(web_data, channelGrouping == channel, select=-channelGrouping)
      filtered_data.long <- melt(filtered_data, id.vars='date')

      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(filtered_data.long, aes(date, value, color=variable))+ggtitle(localChannel)+geom_line()
      })
    })
  }
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("XXXXXX Reporting"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("choose_view"),
      dateRangeInput("dates", "dates") 
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("plots")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

The issue, I believe, is in the placement of the for loop. If I place it where it is above it doesn't seem to have access to `web_data`. If I place it in the `output$plots` block then it seems that `tagList` doesn't output to the UI. I'm sure I'm missing something on scope or similar but I've been staring at it too long now!

**EDIT, following Shayne03's answer:**

I now have the following, which seems closer to working:

```
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    plot_output_list <- lapply(unique(web_data()$channelGrouping), function(i) {
      plotname <- paste0("plot", i)
      plotOutput(plotname)
    })

  }) 

  reactive({

    for (channel in unique(web_data()$channelGrouping)) {

      local({ 
        plotname <- paste0("plot", channel)
        localChannel <- channel
        filtered_data <- subset(web_data(), channelGrouping == channel, 
                                select=-channelGrouping)
        filtered_data.long <- melt(filtered_data, id.vars='date')

        output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
          ggplot(filtered_data.long, aes(date, value, 
                                         color=variable))+ggtitle(localChannel)+geom_line()
        })
      })
    }
  })


  web_data<-reactive({
    #get the GA data, between the dates specified by user
    google_analytics_4(id, 
                       date_range = c(format(input$dates[1]), 
                                      format(input$dates[2])),
                       metrics = c("sessions","pageviews","bounces"),
                       dimensions = c("date", "channelGrouping"),
                       anti_sample = TRUE)
  })
```

If I have the code exactly like that, the plot areas are output in the HTML code, but no graphs. I tried, due to my lack of understanding, to put the reactive block into the renderUI block but got a coercion error. I'm sure it's a typo or something now, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it in the end after some experimentation after Shayne03's answer. In addition to his answer, I needed to put a call to the reactive block which redrew the data at the beginning of the `output$plots` block.

Here's the code which ended up giving me my expected output at this stage:

```
library(shiny)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(googleAnalyticsR)

server <- function(input, output) {

  id <- 'XXXXXXX'

  output$plots <- renderUI({

    updatePlots()

    plot_output_list <- lapply(unique(web_data()$channelGrouping), function(i) {
      plotname <- paste0("plot", i)
      plotOutput(plotname)
    })

    #
  }) 

  updatePlots <- reactive({
    for (channel in unique(web_data()$channelGrouping)) {

      local({ 
        plotname <- paste0("plot", channel)
        localChannel <- channel
        filtered_data <- subset(web_data(), channelGrouping == channel, 
                                select=-channelGrouping)
        filtered_data.long <- melt(filtered_data, id.vars='date')

        print("Hi")
        output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
          ggplot(filtered_data.long, aes(date, value, 
                                         color=variable))+ggtitle(localChannel)+geom_line()
        })
      })
    }
  })


  web_data<-reactive({
    #get the GA data, between the dates specified by user
    google_analytics_4(id, 
                       date_range = c(format(input$dates[1]), 
                                      format(input$dates[2])),
                       metrics = c("sessions","pageviews","bounces"),
                       dimensions = c("date", "channelGrouping"),
                       anti_sample = TRUE)
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("XXXXX Reporting"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("choose_view"),
      dateRangeInput("dates", "dates") 
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("plots")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove web_data from renderUI and place it within a reactive block.

```
web_data<-reactive({
        google_analytics_4(id, 
                           date_range = c(format(input$dates[1]), 
                           format(input$dates[2])),
                           metrics = c("sessions","pageviews","bounces"),
                           dimensions = c("date", "channelGrouping"),
                           anti_sample = TRUE)
})
```

This will make it available to both the renderUI call and the for loop. You just need to call it as a reactive object like below.

```
output$plots <- renderUI({
plot_output_list <- lapply(unique(web_data()$channelGrouping), function(i) {
  plotname <- paste0("plot", i)
  plotOutput(plotname)
})

reactive({
    for (channel in unique(web_data()$channelGrouping)) {
    local({ 
      plotname <- paste0("plot", channel)
      localChannel <- channel
      filtered_data <- subset(web_data(), channelGrouping == channel, 
select=-channelGrouping)
      filtered_data.long <- melt(filtered_data, id.vars='date')

      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(filtered_data.long, aes(date, value, 
color=variable))+ggtitle(localChannel)+geom_line()
  })
})
}
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that's got me close but not quite there. I've edited, any chance you could take another look?